# How to make td tag look like a tag in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some rows that using `ajax` to get data, if I use `a` tag, the browser will be refresh and some data will lost. Then I just use `td` tag, but I want to make it look like `a` tag (color, cursor a hand) [image: cursor a hand]

Here my code:

```
<td style="color: green;" onclick="myFunction(this)">hello</td>
// failed with: <td style="color: green;" onclick="myFunction(this)"><a href="">hello</a></td>
```

Comment: alter its inline css as: `style="color: green; cursor: pointer"`

Comment: Ok, it working, thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following `css` to give `td` look and feel like `a`.

```
td {
    color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

td:focus, td:hover {
    color: #23527c;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Color should work the way you have it.
for cursor you could try

```
td {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `a`, but return `false` after your function and use `#` as `href` value:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(this);return false;">hello</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

While you could do that using the `cursor: pointer` CSS-property, I'd rather use the `<a>` tag and set a click event handler like this:

```
<a id="clickable">Click</a>
<script>
document.getElementById("clickable").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  alert("Clicked")
  e.preventDefault()
  return false
})
</script>
```

[See a working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/o1n960jc/)

Answer (score 1):

A `<td>` tag is actually part of the `<table>` tag and should not be used outside it.

What you're better off doing is simply creating a new button using a `<div>` element and some CSS

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  background: #09c;
  color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #28f;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">My button text</div>
```

- `display: inline-block` causes the `<div>` element to not take up the entire width of the page (just wrap the contents).
- `cursor: pointer` will make the cursor literally look like a pointer when hovering over the element.
- Not using a table tag here makes much more sense since you're not displaying a table (From what I can see in the question).

And that's pretty much it!